# JavaFX. Inset / Outset Border

Tags: java, css, javafx

Доброго времени суток. Собственно, вопрос состоит в том, как сделать в JavaFX рамку типа Inset / Outset. 
P.S.
Желательно, с помощью setStyle.

Answer (score 0):

- за цвет отвечает свойство -fx-border-color
- за ширину отвечает свойство -fx-border-width

Работают схожим образом, на вход подаются либо одно либо 4 значения (top, right, bottom, left). Подробнее можно узнать по ссылке [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html). Свойства связанные именно с border описаны в блоке Region/STROKED BORDERS.